# Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined while using console.log

Tags: javascript, websocket

Im trying to make a simple game cheat detector and I have encountered this problem while testing it. My issue is that when that I try printing the Coordinates it gives me this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined**

I think my problem is because of looping, and its probably really simple, but here is my code:

```
var USrPosX
var USrPosY
setInterval(Chk, 1000)
function Chk() {
 USrPosX = event.clientX
 USrPosY = event.clientY
 console.log(USrPosX)
 console.log(USrPosY)
}
```

Comment: but, `event` isn't defined... from where does it come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the error, is because you never specified "event".
By looking what you are trying to do, i assume you want to get the mouse coordinates. if you are listening for "mousemove" event on the document, you will be able to access the clientX and clientY properties:

```
    var USrPosX;
    var USrPosY;

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    function onMouseMove(event){
        USrPosX = event.clientX;
        USrPosY = event.clientY;
    }

    setInterval(Chk, 1000);

    function Chk(event) {
        console.log(USrPosX)
        console.log(USrPosY)
    }
```

you can see that i get the "event" as a parameter in the event listener "onMouseMove". It is send by the browser whenever the "mousemove" event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved. I didnt know you needed a event-listener for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the mousemove event first.

Here is a corrected version:

```
var USrPosX
var USrPosY
document.onmousemove = Chk;
setInterval(Chk, 1000);
function Chk(event) {
 event = event || window.event;
 USrPosX = event.clientX
 USrPosY = event.clientY
 console.log(USrPosX)
 console.log(USrPosY)
}
```

Comment: This will still not work, since there  is not "event" property in the window object, and also there is no "event" parameter that is send by the "setInterval" function.